# Hibernate EntityManager: remove referenced entity not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager, cascade

I'm currenetly trying hard to delete an entity, that is involved in various relations (Only `@ManyToOne`) - However, Hibernate does not delete anything - after calling `em.remove` everything remains unchanged.

---

I have 5 entities (`E1 - E5`), referencing the entity (`E6`) in question like this:

```
@Entity
public class EX {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "eX", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<E6> e6s;  
}
```

`E6` itself has the reverse `@ManyToOne` Relations:

```
public class E6{

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private E1 e1;       

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private E2 e2;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private E3 e3;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private E4 e4;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private E5 e5;
}
```

(left out ids, additional columns etc...)

---

Whenever I call `em.remove(instanceOfE6)`, simply **nothing** happens. I added Hibernate SQL-Output and cannot see a single attempt of executing a `DELETE` Query.

Since the deletion can happen from an ajax request and a *fresh* EntityManager, I added a call to merge before the deletion, cause otherwhise I get an *Entity unmanaged Exception*:

```
em.remove(em.merge(instanceOfE6));
```

But nothing. State remains unchanged.

So I tried to add an `@PreRemove` Method to clear all the relations before removing the entity... Method gets never called.

I tried various Cascade Operations (Including `Cascade.ALL`) - but since all I need is remove and persist, that should be working as well.

---

I thought about using a native Delete Statement (each entity has a surrogate id, so that would most likely work) - but since everything happens from within an AJAX-call, I don't want to use that, cause I want to have the Persistence-Cache updated without re-fetching every involved Entity...

Any ideas?

If you need more source, just drop me a comment.

---

I also tried to remove the entity in question from ALL relations (object wise), and call `em.merge()` on one of the remaining entities, hoping that hibernate will whipe the unlinked entity - no luck.

Comment: Did you commit the transaction?

Comment: Did you call `em.flush()`?

Comment: @DavidLevesque Running Hibernate in autocommit mode...

Comment: @jmvivo ... and autoflush mode, cause its a single-user application where I just need to keep the persistence context and the database synchronized while i don't have to worry about memory usage or performance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured out the problem(s) - Actual there have been two of them: (Leaving this here, if somebody stumbles across a similar issue)

As I mentioned, the deletion should have happened in an ajax request. Therefore, simple calling

```
em.remove(instanceOfE6);
```

resulted in an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance` exception. So, I tried the approach using merge:

```
em.remove(em.merge(instanceOfE6));
```

which did not produce an error - but simple didn't work. I enabled trace-logging for hibernate as mentioned in this post: [JPA/Hibernate remove entity sometimes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898085/jpa-hibernate-remove-entity-sometimes-not-working) to figure out what went wrong, and indeed, trying to remove the entity resulted in:

```
 TRACE [org...DefaultPersistEventListener] un-scheduling entity deletion ...
```

Obviously the entity to remove is still connected to other entities, which lead to the problem that hibernate aborted the deletion, so i tried to remove the relations before deletion.
As you can see from the example of `E6`, I used `@ManyToOne(optional = false)`, which means I cannot set the outgoing references to null, or it will cause exceptions when calling `merge`.

My first attempt to clean the relations was only "cleaning the sets", because I assumed that cleaning the outgoing relations  of the entity I want to delete is not required. It is not, but i'll outline this in detail a little later:

So, the code now looked like

```
instanceOfE6.getE1().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE2().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE3().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE4().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE5().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);

em.remove(em.merge(instanceOfE6));
```

Same issue: deletion aborted. I missed the obvious fact, that calling `merge` will ofc. restore the entries inside the sets i just removed, **because instanceOfE6 STILL had it's not nullable-references on the other entities**. Therefore deletion was aborted again.

Finally the solution ofc. was to do the the merge before removing the references and the final deletion:

```
if (!em.contains(instanceOfE6)){
   instanceOfE6 = em.merge(instanceOfE6);
}

instanceOfE6.getE1().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE2().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE3().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE4().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);
instanceOfE6.getE5().getE6s().remove(instanceOfE6);

em.remove(instanceOfE6);
```

---

I'm not quite sure if I explained everything 100% accurate, but at least I can reproduce and fix the Issue by changing the code back and forth.

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Have been struggling with this one for two hours. Thanks you very much. People, watch out for entity trees (I had to write groupToRemove.getParent().getSubgroups().remove(groupToRemove), and had to map parent with cascade = CascadeType.MERGE). Cheers

Comment: `groupToRemove.getParent().getSubgroups().remove(groupToRemov‌​e)` that's exactly what I did. It looks f**** strange... but getting into it: It's logical :-)