# How to remove Parent and Child Element in JPA/hibernate inheritance strategy Joined?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a entity Photo mapped in JPA/Hibernate that have three different children (PhotoSpot, PhotoSecteur, PhotoVoie). I used @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED), everything works fine for the persist methods, but I can't manage to make it work when I want to delete one of the photo.

I'm trying to delete a photo just by deleting an element from the parent class, but i don't know if it's possible.
I looked all the other posts about the same topic, and I think the problem may come from the fact that my child entity has a @ManyToOne asssociation. But I put that association in cascade = CascadeType.ALL on the one side.

Here are my entities (I just put the parent and one child), they are all the same:
Here is the parent

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Photo implements Serializable{
    // todo fichier properties
    private static final String CHEMIN = "D:\\fichiers\\";
    private static final int TAILLE_TAMPON = 10240;
    public static final String CHAMP_PHOTO = "photo";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;
    protected String nom;
```

Here is one of the child

```
@Entity
@Table
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
public class PhotoSpot extends Photo {

    @ManyToOne
    private Spot spot;
```

My deleting method :

```
    public boolean deletePhoto(Long id){
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            Photo photo = entityManager.find(Photo.class, id);
            entityManager.remove(photo);
            entityManager.flush();
            Path path = Paths.get(Photo.getCHEMIN()+photo.getNom());
            Files.delete(path);
            transaction.commit();
            return true;
        }catch (Exception e){
            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Does the problem happens because I'm doing it the wrong way, and that I should delete first the child element? Normally the cascade option should allow me to delete the child when I delete the parent. Thanks!

**EDIT :**
Ok as i expected, the problem come from the relations. If I enable the org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener im getting the `un-scheduling entity deletion` like a lot of other people. I checked this [JPA/Hibernate remove entity sometimes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898085/jpa-hibernate-remove-entity-sometimes-not-working/16901857#16901857) this [Hibernate EntityManager: remove referenced entity not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349213/hibernate-entitymanager-remove-referenced-entity-not-working) and this [Prevent Hibernate from deleting orphaned entities while merging an entity having entity associations with orphanRemoval set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004855/prevent-hibernate-from-deleting-orphaned-entities-while-merging-an-entity-having/34240940#34240940), but idon't understand exactly what it implies to do in my heritage case. I tried to remove manually the association, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

whenever parent delete then all children automatically deleted

```
class Product {
    String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    List<AProduct> aProduct;
}

class AProduct {
    String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    Product product;
}
```

Comment: Thaanks for your answer ! Just to be sure, do you mean i should replace the heritage by simple associations ?

Comment: yes and you can also move your code Photo photo = entityManager.find(Photo.class, id);code in service class and why you create transaction by own give all to framework just use the entity manager's methods.

Comment: Ok thanks, i will try that tomorrow. The transaction ? Im not using spring so i guess i have to do it by hand no ?

Comment: I thought about your solution, but i'm not sure it fits my project (or maybe i don't understand it properly).There is no a toMany relations between my table photo and the childs. Its clearly an inheritance scheme for me. All PhotoSpot, PhotoSecteur and PhotoVoie are... Photos. Or i should reverse my relation having the PhotoSecteur, PhotoVoie, PhotoSpot ont the side one and the Entity Photo on the side Many. But normmaly with inheritance i should be able to delete everything properly, wiithout changing my structure.