# Hibernate members deletion not seen further within transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions, jta

I'm using Hibernate with JTA (container managed transactions).

Let's say I have the following model: Employee with many-to-one relations to Office and Team. I've set up bidirectional associations.

```
class Employee{
   Office office;
   Team team;
}

class Office{
   List<Employee> employees;
}

class Team{
   List<Employee> employees;
}
```

Now the data:

Emp 1 with Ofc 1 and Team 1

Emp 2 with Ofc 1 and Team 2

The problem:
I iterate over the Team 1 employees (i.e. just emp 1) and delete them.
Then within the same transaction I execute HQL select to get Ofc 1. Now within Ofc 1 employees list I expect to find just emp 2 (since emp 1 has been deleted on the previous step) but the result is that both employees are still there.

I tried flushing the entity manager after the deletion: same thing.

Comment: I had a same kind of error but in my case flushing the *session* after the delete did the trick

Comment: I tried the following:
em.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class).flush();

No success.

Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

As required by JPA standard, Hibernate will [unschedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898085/jpa-hibernate-remove-entity-sometimes-not-working) removal if `PERSIST` operation is applied/cascaded to the removed entity.

Make sure to remove all references to the deleted entity from all the other managed entity instances.