# Removing and persisting the same entity in a row in the same transaction in EJB using JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

I have a very special case where I need to update a primary key which is disallowed by JPA (EclipseLink 2.6.0). Therefore, the entity is first deleted and then inserted with new values.

The tables involved have a predefined structure being required by GlassFish Server for JAAS authentication.

```sql
mysql> describe user_role_table;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id     | varchar(176)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| password    | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| row_version | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe group_table;
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_group_id | varchar(176)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| group_id      | varchar(15)         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| row_version   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+---------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`user_group_id` and `group_id` together form a composite primary key. `group_id` in `group_table` is a foreign key referencing `user_id` in `user_role_table`. `GroupTable` holds an `@EmbeddedId` from an `@Embeddable` class, `GroupTablePK`.

This information will seldom be needed. Therefore, I am not posting the entity classes involved.

---

An update is attempted to be simulated by first removing the supplied entity, `GroupTable` and then persisting the same entity using a new value of `group_id` as follows (in an EJB using CMT).

<sub>Again, this is a very special case and even updating a user's authority is fairly rare. Just that it is worth providing the functionality beforehand.</sub>

```
public GroupTable update(GroupTable groupTable, String userId, String oldGroupId) {
    String newGropuId = groupTable.getGroupTablePK().getGroupId();
    groupTable.getGroupTablePK().setGroupId(oldGropuId);

    if (delete(groupTable)) {
        // entityManager.flush();
        groupTable.setUserRoleTable(entityManager.getReference(UserRoleTable.class, userId));
        groupTable.getGroupTablePK().setGroupId(newGropuId);
        entityManager.persist(groupTable);
    }

    return groupTable;
}
```

```
public boolean delete(GroupTable groupTable) {
    groupTable.setUserRoleTable(entityManager.getReference(UserRoleTable.class, groupTable.getUserRoleTable().getUserId()));
    GroupTable managedGroupTable = entityManager.merge(groupTable);
    managedGroupTable.getUserRoleTable().getGroupTableList().remove(groupTable);
    entityManager.remove(managedGroupTable);
    return !entityManager.contains(managedGroupTable);
}
```

These methods are executed in the same transaction and they do their job pretty well but only if the only commented line inside the `update()` method is uncommented. Otherwise, it complains about a duplicate entry for a primary key in the `group_table` - the entity which is to be removed first is not removed prior to persisting that entity causing a duplicate insert to spawn.

Why is `entityManager.flush();` required prior to persisting the entity? It is an additional round trip to the database and should be avoided.

Comment: It is required because otherwise, persist cancels out your delete call, so you are just changing the primary key.  Changing a primary key is not allowed in JPA, which is why you are trying to work around it with the delete/persist.  It really would be better for you to clone the entity and then update the clone's pk.  EclipseLInk has clone methods and policies to help accomplish this, and using a clone more accurately represents what you are doing - identity is fundamental to an entity and so a new identity requires a new entity.

Comment: This is somewhat not as intuitive as it looks like as the delete call is suspended even though a detached instance is attempted to persist after delete. Looks something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30996141/1391249).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid an additional database round trip through `EntityManager#flush();`, I used EclipseLink specific [`CopyGroup`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/CopyGroup.html) to clone the specified entity before persisting it to the database as suggested by Chris in the comment section below the question. Such as,

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaEntityManager;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.CopyGroup;

public GroupTable update(GroupTable groupTable, UserTable userTable, String oldGroupId) {
    String newGroupId = groupTable.getGroupTablePK().getGroupId();
    groupTable.getGroupTablePK().setGroupId(oldGroupId);
    GroupTable copy = null;

    if (delete(groupTable)) {

        CopyGroup copyGroup = new CopyGroup();
        copyGroup.setShouldResetPrimaryKey(true);
        copyGroup.setShouldResetVersion(true);
        copyGroup.setDepth(CopyGroup.CASCADE_PRIVATE_PARTS); // Implicit in this case.

        copy = (GroupTable) entityManager.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).copy(groupTable, copyGroup);

        GroupTablePK groupTablePK = new GroupTablePK();
        groupTablePK.setGroupId(newGroupId);
        groupTablePK.setUserGroupId(groupTable.getGroupTablePK().getUserGroupId());

        copy.setGroupTablePK(groupTablePK);
        copy.getUserRoleTable().getGroupTableList().clear();
        UserRoleTable managedUserRoleTable = entityManager.find(UserRoleTable.class, userTable.getEmailId());
        copy.setUserRoleTable(managedUserRoleTable);
        managedUserRoleTable.getGroupTableList().add(copy); // Use a defensive link management method instead.
        entityManager.persist(copy);
    }

    return copy;
}
```

<sub>The `delete()` method as shown in the question is left untouched.</sub>

[`CopyGroup.CASCADE_PRIVATE_PARTS`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/CopyGroup.html#CASCADE_PRIVATE_PARTS) is the default depth level, If `CopyGroup` has no attribute/s specified **explicitly**, indicating only the relationship/s being privately owned are cloned along with all other attributes in the entity.

If `CopyGroup` however, specifies at least one attribute **explicitly** (using [`CopyGroup#addAttribute()`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/CopyGroup.html#addAttribute(java.lang.String,%20org.eclipse.persistence.core.queries.CoreAttributeGroup))), then the default depth level is [`CopyGroup.CASCADE_TREE`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/CopyGroup.html#CASCADE_TREE) which only copies the attribute/s as specified by `addAttribute()`.

> [`CopyGroup#setShouldResetPrimaryKey(true)`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/CopyGroup.html#setShouldResetPrimaryKey(boolean)) - Set if the primary
>   key should be reset to null.
>   [`CopyGroup#setShouldResetVersion(true)`](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.6/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/CopyGroup.html#setShouldResetVersion(boolean)) - Set if the version
>   should be reset to null.

---

**Additional :**

If `CopyGroup#setShouldResetVersion(true)` (with `true`) is used along with anyone of `CASCADE_PRIVATE_PARTS`, `CASCADE_ALL_PARTS` or `NO_CASCADE`, then the primary key attribute/s of the cloned object will not be set.

If `CopyGroup#setShouldResetVersion(false)` (with `false`) is used along with `CASCADE_TREE`, then the primary key attribute/s will be copied/set. Otherwise, if it is given `true` (using `CASCADE_TREE`), then the primary key attribute/s which are not specified with `CopyGroup#addAttribute()` will not be set (unless explicitly specified i.e. one needs to be explicit).

More details about `CopyGroup` can be found in the following link.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup#CopyGroup

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate docs says,

> Flushing is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent
>   store with persistable state held in memory.

So `flush()` will synchronize your persistent state (in your case it is deleted `groupTable` by calling delete(groupTable)) with underlying database. In shorts after `flush` hibernate will write these changes in DB.

So when you comment `entityManager.flush();` hibernate won't synchronize (write) the changes with database, resulting it complains about a duplicate entry for a primary key in the group_table. So it's necessary to call `flush` in this case.

Note: `flush()` may be useful to persist the data in between the ongoing transaction & then finally `commit` the changes. So you can also rollback the previous changes if there occurs some problem afterwards, like for batch insert/update.

Comment: I am accepting my own answer because it actually functions for me. Thank you :)